# kubernetes ingress controller and resource using nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Can anybody provide me a complete example about how running insecure (without TLS) ingress controller and resource with nginx to have remote access to services running inside kubernetes cluster ? i did not find something useful.

PS: my kubernetes cluster is running on bare metal, not on a cloud provider.
the next may be useful information about what i did:

## $kubectl get svc

`NAME                CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
    attachmentservice   10.254.111.232   <none>        80/TCP     3d
    financeservice      10.254.38.228    <none>        80/TCP     3d
    gatewayservice      10.254.38.182    nodes         80/TCP     3d
    hrservice           10.254.61.196    <none>        80/TCP     3d
    kubernetes          10.254.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    31d
    messageservice      10.254.149.125   <none>        80/TCP     3d
    redis-service       10.254.201.241   <none>        6379/TCP   15d
    settingservice      10.254.157.155   <none>        80/TCP     3d
    trainingservice     10.254.166.92    <none>        80/TCP     3d`

## nginx-ingress-rc.yml

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-rc
    labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        app: nginx-ingress
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
        containers:
        - image: nginxdemos/nginx-ingress:0.6.0
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            hostPort: 80`

## services-ingress.yml

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: services-ingress
spec:
    rules:
    - host: ctc-cicd2
        http:
            paths:
            - path: /gateway
                backend:
                serviceName: gatewayservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /training
                backend:
                serviceName: trainingservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /attachment
                backend:
                serviceName: attachmentservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /hr
                backend:
                serviceName: hrservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /message
                backend:
                serviceName: messageservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /settings
                backend:
                serviceName: settingservice
                servicePort: 80
            - path: /finance
                backend:
                serviceName: financeservice
                servicePort: 80`

## nginx.conf new content

```
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-trainingservice {

    server 12.16.64.5:8190;
    server 12.16.65.6:8190;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-attachmentservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.2:8095;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-hrservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.7:8077;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-messageservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.9:8065;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-settingservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.10:8098;
    server 12.16.65.4:8098;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-financeservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.4:8092;
```

`}
upstream default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-gatewayservice {`

```
    server 12.16.64.6:8090;
    server 12.16.65.7:8090;
```

}`

`server {
        listen 80;`

```
    server_name ctc-cicd2;





    location /gateway {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-gatewayservice;

    }
    location /training {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-trainingservice;

    }
    location /attachment {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-attachmentservice;

    }
    location /hr {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-hrservice;

    }
    location /message {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-messageservice;

    }
    location /settings {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-settingservice;

    }
    location /finance {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            client_max_body_size 1m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffering on;

            proxy_pass http://default-services-ingress-ctc-cicd2-financeservice;

    }
```

`}`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Kubernetes ingress documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/), Ingress is a collection of rules that allow inbound connections to reach the cluster services. This, of course requires that you have an ingress controller deployed in your cluster. While there are many many ways you can implement an ingress controller, a simple one that will help you understand the concept can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx-alpha). This one is written in `golang` and basically listens to the kubeapi for new ingress resources. When it gets a new incoming ingress resource, it will recreate a new nginx conf based off that config and reload the nginx container that makes up your ingress controller:

```
const (
    nginxConf = `
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_names_hash_max_size 512;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
{{range $ing := .Items}}
{{range $rule := $ing.Spec.Rules}}
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{$rule.Host}};
{{ range $path := $rule.HTTP.Paths }}
    location {{$path.Path}} {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://{{$path.Backend.ServiceName}}.{{$ing.Namespace}}.svc.cluster.local:{{$path.Backend.ServicePort}};
    }{{end}}
  }{{end}}{{end}}
}`
)
```

What this allows for is one single entry point into your cluster that proxy traffic to all of the services inside of your Kubernetes cluster.

Say you have a service named `foo` inside the namespace `bar`. Kube-DNS allows us to reach that service from inside a kubernetes cluster form the DNS address `foo.bar.svc.cluster.local`. This is basically what Ingress does for us. We specify a path in which we want to use to reach the service and then the ingress controller proxies that path to the service `foo` in your cluster.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, all you said was clear to me. i made some changes to the post. can you find out what was done wrong ? Other thing, what means 'host' tag in the ingress yml file ?

Comment: see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) to learn more about the `host` directive. Also, are you running into an error? what is your question exactly.

Comment: while running the above yml files, i cannot reach my services from outside using for instance curl as following:
curl http://ctc-cicd2/gateway
note in this case that "ctc-cicd2" is the server domain name where nginx-controller is running as a pod